# How to install linberry for Blackberry Bold?

Tags: usb, connection, blackberry

I've bought a Blackberry Bold 9700, and I need to connect it to my computer, reading in some blogs knew linberry, but when I looked for it in software center I didn't find it. could someone explain me how to install it by terminal or if it has another name. Help

Answer (score 1):

In the software centre> search "blackberry" see the results below
This is what Ubuntu offers

[image]

you can download **LinBerry** which is a third-party application from here: http://linberry.webcindario.com/index.html

I did not see any installation instructions only to sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i nombre_del_paquete.deb

Comment: And for install it?

Comment: You just needed to look on the web site.  http://puntoazul.hostoi.com/linberry/linberry1.1b1a_i386deb.tar.gz

Comment: thanks @bluexrider . I'm nwe user. and I don't understand too much this sistem

Comment: could I INSTALL IT BY A CODE LIKE >  apt-get install ?